# Google Analytics 360

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk, google-analytics-filters

One of our client having google analytics 360 premium account.I written script in java for fetching a data of my website from google analytics using core reporting API v4 with proper credential. Can i use same script for google Analytics 360 for my client or  is there a separate API for google analytics 360 for fetching a data from this account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your existing scripts. Google 360 has some extra API features (like an API to pull [unsampled reports](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/unsampled-reports)) but things that work with standard GA work with the commercial version, too.

Comment: Thanks Eike Pierstroff